# How to update the recyclerview that has deleted all data

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am migrating from SQL to ORM Room. I followed a tutorial, it usually worked to insert data, but when I delete an item it does not disappear. I have to open and close the App to show it is gone.

The tutorial I followed is this: https://medium.com/@anujguptawork/note-making-application-using-sqlite-vs-room-part-2-using-room-becf92672e29

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Contrato.MainViewInterface {

@BindView(R.id.recyclerHome)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

private HomeAdapter adapter;
private List<Clientes> clientesList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    initViews();
    loadNotes();
}

private void initViews() {

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}

private void loadNotes(){
    ClienteRepository.getInstance(this).getNotes(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.fabAdicionar)
public void addNote(){
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdicionarActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

@OnClick(R.id.buttonDeletar)
public void buttonDeletar(){
    ClienteRepository.getInstance(this).deletarNotes();
}

@Override
public void onNotesLoaded(List<Clientes> clientesList) {
    clientesList = clientesList;

    if(clientesList.size() == 0){
        onDataNotAvailable();
    }else {
        adapter = new HomeAdapter(this, clientesList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDataNotAvailable() {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Adicione uma nota",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

```
public class ClienteRepository {
private Context context;
private static ClienteRepository _instance;
private ClienteRoomDatabase db;

public static ClienteRepository getInstance(Context context) {
    if (_instance == null) {
        _instance = new ClienteRepository(context);
    }
    return _instance;
}

public ClienteRepository(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    db = ClienteRoomDatabase.getClienteDatabase(context);
}

public void getNotes(final Contrato.MainViewInterface mainViewInterface) {
    db.clienteDAO().getAllClientes().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Consumer<List<Clientes>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(List<Clientes> notes) throws Exception {
            mainViewInterface.onNotesLoaded(notes);
        }
    });
}

public void addNotes(final Contrato.AddNoteViewInterface addNoteViewInterface, final String nome) {
    Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            Clientes clientes = new Clientes(nome);
            db.clienteDAO().insert(clientes);
        }
    }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            addNoteViewInterface.onNoteAdded();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            addNoteViewInterface.onDataNotAvailable();
        }
    });
}

public void deletarNotes() {
    Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            db.clienteDAO().deleteAll();
        }
    }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
        }
    });
}
```

}

```
@Dao
public interface ClienteDAO {

@Insert
void insert(Clientes clientes);

@Query("DELETE FROM table_clientes")
void deleteAll();

@Query("SELECT * FROM table_clientes ORDER BY name ASC")
Maybe<List<Clientes>> getAllClientes();
}
```

Comment: One thing I'm noticing is that you're creating a new HomeAdapter every time the notes are loaded. It's better to keep the same HomeAdapter, and just inform the adapter that the items have changed. You can so this with methods like `notifyItemChanged/Removed/etc`. This requires you to keep track of which items are actually different, though. An easier solution is to just call `notifyDataSetChanged`, but this can have some undesired visual effects (e.g. items animating as if they've changed, even if they haven't). The BEST solution is to use DiffUtil to do the work for you.

Comment: And how could I fix this, could you give me an example?

Comment: ListAdapter is a RecycleView adapter that you can subclass, which does a lot of the DiffUtil stuff for you. You just have to provide the ItemCallback. The documentation has a usage example that uses Room:  

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter  

Notice how, in the example, they don't make a new adapter every time the list is updated. They just call `submitList` on the existing adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Remove item from your dataset of your adapter then call `adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)`